# Как найти самый похожий String в Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, функции

мне нужно найти самый похожий String в Array,что-то типа:

```js
const arr = ["toster","tester","tescer"] 
const str = "tescor"
compare(arr,str) /// return "tescer"
```

Можно ли это сделать,если да то как?

Comment: `"aasaaa"` — кому должна быть похожа? Одна общая буква, остальное отличается)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=levenshtein&ranking=popularity

Comment: этот пакет кажется удобным https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-levenshtein. выбираешь наименьшее расстояние

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Самое первое которое попалось

Comment: @nörbörnën,сейчас посмотрю

Comment: @KristalkillPlay дополнил ответ информацией для общего развития

Comment: Ок,спасибо огромное

Comment: всегда рад поучаствовать в нормальном вопросе :)

Comment: @nörbörnën,слушайте,а возможно что-то подобное реализовать с map,просто как я знаю сортировки с мапом нету?

Comment: не понимаю вопрос

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Выбор способа вычисления близости строк очень сильно зависит от решаемой задачи.

Классическим подходом является вычисление расстояния Левенштейна.

> Расстояние Левенштейна (редакционное расстояние, дистанция
> редактирования) — метрика, измеряющая разность между двумя
> последовательностями символов. Она определяется как минимальное
> количество односимвольных операций (а именно вставки, удаления,
> замены), необходимых для превращения одной последовательности символов
> в другую. В общем случае, операциям, используемым в этом
> преобразовании, можно назначить разные цены. Широко используется в
> теории информации и компьютерной лингвистике.

```
const levenshtein = require('fast-levenshtein');

function compare(str, arr) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => levenshtein.get(str, a) - levenshtein.get(str, b))[0];
}

const arr = ['toster','tester','tescer'];
const str = 'tescor';
console.log(compare(str, arr)); // tescer
```

---

Но существуют подходы к вычислению расстояния, которые лучше подходят для задач, связанных с естественными языками. Рекомендую ознакомиться с документацией к модулю [natural](https://www.npmjs.com/package/natural#string-distance).

```
const natural = require('natural');

function compareJaroWinkler(str, array) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => natural.JaroWinklerDistance(str, b) - natural.JaroWinklerDistance(str, a))[0];
}

const arr = ['концерт в омске', 'концерт в комске', 'концерт в москве'];
const str = 'концерт в томске';

console.log('->', str);
console.log('<-', compareJaroWinkler(str, arr));


-> концерт в томске
концерт в омске 0.9874999999999999
концерт в комске 0.9483333333333334
концерт в москве 0.9616666666666668
<- концерт в омске
```

Answer (score 2):

Я нашёл немного больше подходящею либу:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-most-similar

```
    const findMostSimilar = require('find-most-similar');

    const source = 'book';

    const words = ['lock', 'block', 'back', 'hack'];

    findMostSimilar(source, words); // returns 'back'
```

Comment: это тоже Левенштейн "Use Levenshtein distance alg to find the most similar word in an array to the target word". Но этой библиотекой никто не пользуется...

Comment: Я знаю,просто именно в данном случае использовать её проще.