# Система Левенштейна возвращает неожидаемый результат

Tags: javascript, node.js, алгоритм, levenshtein

Есть такие данные:

```js
const levenshtein = require('fast-levenshtein');
let arr = [  
  'баги',
  'bots',
  'чат',
  'ботыад',
  'информация'
]
```

Использую такой код:

```js
let str = 'бот'
arr.sort((a, b) => levenshtein.get(str , a) - levenshtein.get(str, b))[0]
```

Возвращает:

```
'чат'
```

А должно быть:

```
'ботыад'
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: давай еще раз: Левенштейн не вычисляет на сколько слова похожи, а определяет минимальное количество односимвольных операций (а именно вставки, удаления, замены), необходимых для превращения одной последовательности символов в другую. Вполне нормально, что в твоём забеге побеждает другое короткое слово, т.е. минимальное число операций (замен). Загляни во вторую часть моего ответа, если тебе нужна близость в контексте естественных языков

Comment: OK, спасибо оргомное

Comment: не знаю зачем закрывают твой вопрос, лично я вполне понимаю твоё удивление

Comment: @nörbörnën С такой постановкой вопроса: "у меня есть код, что с ним не так", никто и код смотреть не будет. Помогите лучше новичку освоится.

Comment: если ты пытаешься из сообщений пользователя выбрать какие-то триггрерные слова (в том числе и написанные с ошибкой) то можешь использовать подход, который предлагается в [статье](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/05/21/simple-autocomplete-and-correction-suggestion/#attachment_413). Если же задача "понимать" ввод пользователя то это уже нейросетки с бизнес-грамматиками

Comment: @0xdb, нормальный вопрос для того, кто впервые столкнулся с языком

Comment: @nörbörnën Нормальнм он станет если переформулировать: "Есть это, ожидаю получить то-то и то-то, а получаю вот это".  Перед тем, как столкнуться с языком (программирования), надо освоить язык челевеческий, и научится чётко формулировать свою задачу. Без этого в дальнейшем будет трудно.

Comment: @0xdb так нужно было?

Comment: @KristalkillPlay Да, именно так.

Comment: @nörbörnën Готовте ответ, скоро переоткроется.

Comment: 1) ошибка в вопросе: если бы в массиве arr было слово "боты" то выбрано было бы оно. 2) опишите примерно специфику задачи, которую вы решаете. 3) решение-то я подберу, но надо быть готовым, что без спецсредств, в конечном итоге, мы начнём путать "пугачёва в омске" и "пугачёва в томске". не люблю я все эти угадайки

Comment: 1. Там слово ботыад,можете проверить,выберает чат.

Comment: (спасибо что тогда написали о natural,с ним работает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот вопрос является продолжением вопроса [Как найти самый похожий String в Array](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1187249/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B9-string-%D0%B2-array) по этому и ответ на него является продолжением ответа.

В прошлом ответе я показал как применить [Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) (не подошло автору) и [Сходство Джаро — Винклера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0).

В этом ответе покажу как использовать

- [cтемминг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3), чтобы упростить поиск совпадений (стеммер - это такая штука, которая превратит ("боту", "бота", "ботом") в "бот". ну, если это слово есть в его словаре или если угадает правила по которым искать "основу" слова)
- [Коэффициент Сёренсена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82_%D0%A1%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Плюс, по сравнению с предыдущим ответом, поиск максимального совпадения теперь в один проход, без сортировки.

```
const natural = require('natural');

natural.PorterStemmerRu.attach();

const userMessage = 'пешу в ппаддержку11! бот-заебот! надоели баги вашего ббота!';

const arr = userMessage.tokenizeAndStem(); // ["пеш","паддержку11","бот","заебот","надоел","баг","ваш","ббот"]

['поддержка', 'бот', 'ытот'].forEach((str) => {
    console.log('[d]', str, '->', compareDiceCoefficient(str, arr, 0.5));
    console.log('[j]', str, '->', compareJaroWinkler(str, arr, 0.7));
});


function compareDiceCoefficient(str, arr, lowerLimit = 0.05) {
    // arr.forEach((x) => console.log('[d]', x, natural.DiceCoefficient(str, x)));
    const reduced = arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
        const dt = natural.DiceCoefficient(str, x);
        if (acc.dt < dt && dt > lowerLimit) {
            acc.dt = dt;
            acc.w = x;
        }
        return acc;
    }, {dt: -Infinity, w: null});
    return reduced.w;
}

function compareJaroWinkler(str, arr, lowerLimit = 0.05) {
    // arr.forEach((x) => console.log('[j]', x, natural.JaroWinklerDistance(str, x, undefined, true)));
    const reduced = arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
        const dt = natural.JaroWinklerDistance(str, x, undefined, true);
        if (acc.dt < dt && dt > lowerLimit) {
            acc.dt = dt;
            acc.w = x;
        }
        return acc;
    }, {dt: -Infinity, w: null});
    return reduced.w;
}
```

---

```
[d] поддержка -> ппаддержку11
[j] поддержка -> ппаддержку11
[d] бот -> бот
[j] бот -> бот
[d] ытот -> null
[j] ытот -> null
```

Comment: чтоб вопрос даром не пропадал показал как происпользовать стеммер

Comment: Спасибо огромное ещё раз.

Comment: @KristalkillPlay подумай про то чтобы использовать стеммер, это немного упростит тебе жизнь. стеммер - это такая штука, которая превратит ("боту", "бота", "ботом") в "бот". ну, если это слово есть в его словаре или если угадает правила по которым искать "основу" слова

Comment: Ок,спасибо,попробую использовать стеммер.