# Фильтр слов и фраз на Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет.
Есть функция, которая принимает текст. В ней есть массив со словами и фразами. Текст нужно проверить как на слова, так и на фразы. Если слово или фраза найдена - возвращать true.
Пробовал много вариантов. Регулярные выражения, .some, .includes, засплитать и через многомерные циклы, но не помогло.
Через .includes не работает, потому что если в тексте есть слово "рабочем", а в массиве - "бо", то он не пропускает.
Как быть?)

Суть основной задачи заключается в том, чтобы найти точное совпадение фразы или слова. Коэффициенты или код, который упрощает поиск не нужен.

У нас есть массив - ['собака', 'бо', 'продам бо', 'продам кота']

И текст:

'Продам красивую собаку' - должен пропускать

'Продам красивого котика' - должен пропускать

'Продам кота за бесплатно' - не пропускает

'Продам достойного кота за бесплатно' - должен пропускать

'Продам робота в рабочем состоянии' - должен пропускать

'Продам бо зепчик' - не пропускает

И так далее, думаю суть Вы уловили

includes:

```
for (const word of bannedWords) {
    if (text.includes(word)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Рег. выражение:

```
  for (const phrase of bannedWords) {
    const escapedPhrase = phrase.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
    const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${escapedPhrase}\\b`, 'i');
    if (regex.test(text)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
```

Остальное особо не имеет смысла, потому что в массиве bannedWords есть как слова, так и фразы. Поэтому сплитать текст бессмысленно.

Comment: Добавить ваш код с попытками + пример входящих данных и ожидаемый результат, что бы было более понятно, какого результата вы хотите достичь

Comment: проблема в `\b` и неанглийских символах

Comment: предполагается что будет только русский текст?

Comment: я писал тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1187256/2659 и тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1190030/2659 как можно решать такие языковые задачки

Comment: @nörbörnën суть основной задачи заключается в том, чтобы найти точное совпадение фразы или слова. Коэффициенты или код, который упрощает поиск не нужен. 

У нас есть массив - 
['собака', 'бо', 'продам бо', 'продам кота']

И текст:
'Продам красивую собаку' - должен пропускать
'Продам красивого котика' - должен пропускать
'Продам кота за бесплатно' - не пропускает
'Продам робота в рабочем состоянии' - должен пропускать
'Продам бо зепчик' - не пропускает

И так далее, думаю суть Вы уловили

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос.

Для тех, кто в поисках ответа +- на такую же задачу, дело было в регулярке:

```
function checkBannedWords (text) {
  const bannedWords = ['бо', 'group in riga', 'одного человека на', 'бошки'];
  
  for (const bannedWord of bannedWords) {
    const regEx = new RegExp((?:(?<=\\s)|^)${bannedWord}(?=(\\s|\\.|$)), 'i');
    if (regEx.test(text)) {
      return true
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

checkBannedWords('Есть отличная group in riga')
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте переделать эту функцию [полноконтекстного поиска](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) объекта. Если нужно на JavaScript, а не TypeScript, перегоните [через онлайн компилятор](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?)

```js
export const compareFulltext = <T extends Record<string, any>>(data: T, search: string, ...keys: string[]) => {
  const target = String(search || "")
    .toLowerCase()
    .split(" ");
  const filterFn = (key: string) => {
    const source = String(data[key] || "")
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(" ");
    return target.every(function (term) {
      return source.some((word) => word.includes(term));
    });
  };
  let isOk = false;
  for (const key of keys) {
    isOk = isOk || filterFn(key);
  }
  return isOk;
};

export default compareFulltext;
```

Пример использования

```js
const arr = [
    {
        building: `"ЖК" Голден Хаус`,
        owner: "Сергей П.",
    },
    {
        building: `"ЖК" Эллизиум`,
        owner: "Александр М.",
    },
    {
        building: `"ЖК" Золотая долина`,
        owner: "Владимир Е.",
    },
    {
        building: `"ЖК" Золотая долина`,
        owner: "Анатолий О.",
    },
];


arr.find((entry) => compareFulltext(entry, "жк голден", "owner", "building")) // {building: '"ЖК" Голден Хаус', owner: 'Сергей П.'}


arr.find((entry) => compareFulltext(entry, "сергей", "owner", "building")) // {building: '"ЖК" Голден Хаус', owner: 'Сергей П.'}
```

Обратите внимание, функция сама игнорирует верхний регистр символов, игнорирует мусор типа ковычек, поддерживает игнор словестного мусора типа предлогов и тд

```js
const removeSubstring = (text: string, ...remove: string[]) => {
    let result = text;
    remove.forEach((item) => result = result.split(item).join('').trim());
    return result;
};

removeSubstring("удивительное наименование файла", "удивительное", "файла") // наименование
```

Для фильтрации же строк по черному списку можно использовать функцию выше